# Global Variable undefined phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, camera

Im developing an android application in phonegap, in which i click on button , i take a picture from photo library of the device. i display it in my application then a pop up is shown asking me if i want to confirm uploading the image to server (I use Filetransfer to upload the image).

Everything is working fine , except one thing. when can take the picture , i display it and i can upload it. the problem now that when i upload the picture , in my win(r) function i have a variable "r.response" , i should send it to the server. that's why i create a global variable "imageServer" that takes the values of r.response and i call it from another function. but when i alert it tells me undefined. Here is my code.

```
var imageServer;

function uploadPhoto(imageData)
{

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageData, encodeURI("Server Url"), win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) 
{
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);        
    imageServer = r.response;
    //alert(imageServer);// Here when i alert i should get the url of the picture
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) 
{
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);

} 

function SendServer()
{
    alert(imageServer); // when i alert here i get undefined 

    var callDatasetPosition = JSON.stringify({'serviceName':"global_functions", 'methodName':'setPosition',"parameters":[imageServer]});// here when i see in server side , there is no url of image send
    $.post('server url', callDatasetPosition, function(resp){}).done(function(data) 
    {               
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    }); 
}
```

Can you help me please. Thanks a lot

Comment: try localStorage.setItem("imageServer", r.bytesSent) and get in SendServer() function alert(localStorage.getItem("imageServer"))

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i tried it in alert alert(localStorage.getItem("imageServer")); i get null